# gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.run unrecognized arguments: --temp-location

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, buildkite

I'm providing both a staging and temp location via the `gcloud dataflow flex-template run` CLI. These are both valid optional flags ([as per docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/run)) and there isn't any mention that you [should or shouldn't provide both](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#understand_staging_location_and_temp_location).

**Why else would this error come up?**

> ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.run) unrecognized arguments:
> --temp-location (did you mean '--staging-location'?)
> gs://gcs-bucket-name

*Edit: adding context as requested*

The process is executing within a Buildkite CI/CD pipeline, so generally speaking a Buildkite agent/step calls a gcloud Docker container which runs a bash script. I'm also able to run this command and container combo locally just fine -- the error is only present while running in the pipeline

`Dockerfile`

```docker
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk

COPY docker/scripts/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh /app/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh

WORKDIR /app

# RUN sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk <-- threw error

ENTRYPOINT "/app/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh"
```

`gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh`

```bash
gcloud dataflow flex-template run ${JOB_NAME} \
    --template-file-gcs-location ${TEMPLATE_PATH}.json \
    --region us-central1 \
    --staging-location ${GCS_PATH}/staging/${JOB_NAME} \
    --temp-location ${GCS_PATH}/temp \
        --parameters requirements_file=requirements.txt \
        --parameters input_subscription=${INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION} \
        --parameters output_table=${OUTPUT_TABLE} \
        --parameters subject=${SUBJECT} \
        --parameters schema_registry_url=${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL} \
    --subnetwork=${SUBNETWORK} \
    --service-account-email=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}
```

Comment: Can you share the complete command with fake values please ?

Comment: Is your gcloud CLI updated? I tried to specify both `--temp-location` and `--staging-location` and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the responses @MazlumTosun @BrunoVolpato I've added context and will double check the gcloud version (this is a good suggestion). It shouldn't be an issue because the `flex-template` arg is part of the new beta version, and would error out differently if it were an old version

Comment: Why you don't directly use the official `google cloud sdk` image : `google/cloud-sdk:412.0.0` ?
Can you give use the exact `gcloud sdk` your image returns please ?

Comment: adding the image tag did the trick! feel free to convert your comments to a response @MazlumTosun and I'll accept as the answer:
`FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:408.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I proposed in my comment, you can use the offical `google` `sdk` image with the latest version :

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:412.0.0

COPY docker/scripts/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh /app/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh

WORKDIR /app

# RUN sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk <-- threw error

ENTRYPOINT "/app/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh"
```

or

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:408.0.1

COPY docker/scripts/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh /app/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh

WORKDIR /app

# RUN sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk <-- threw error

ENTRYPOINT "/app/gcloud-deploy-flex-template.sh"
```